# Migrating disks from one NAS to a new one (Synology)?

Tags: raid, nas, synology

I am thinking to buy new disks for my DS413 and run SHR-2 until either I find my NAS too slow or if it fails for whatever reason.

Is it possible to just buy a new Synology NAS and exchange the disks?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an identical hardware raid controller. Getting a new but otherwise identical NAS and transferring the disks in should work. Getting a newer NAS from the same company might work if you are lucky.

A more expensive but fool proof option is to buy a new NAS complete with disks, and transfer the data to it via the network.

Comment: You don't really answer the question, afaik SHR-2 is a software raid, so it should not depend on any raid controller. I don't want to be lucky, I want to make sure SHR-1, SHR2 are compatible across other synology hardware